# Is AngularDart 4 compatible with Dart 2 & build_runner 0.8?

Tags: dart, angular-dart

Currently on

- Dart VM version: 2.0.0-dev.49.0
- angular ^4.0.0
- Linux
- Dartium

One of the upgrade requirement for Dart 2 upgrade @ https://webdev-dartlang-org-dev.firebaseapp.com/dart-2 is to use `build_runner 0.8` which from the error code is not compatible with Angular4.

My `pubspec.yaml` looks like

```
name: JRapha
description: A web app that uses AngularDart Components
version: 0.0.1
environment:
  sdk: '>=2.0.0-dev.49.0 <2.0.0'
dependencies:
  angular: ^4.0.0
dev_dependencies:
  angular_test: ^1.0.0
  test: ^0.12.30
  build_runner: ^0.8.2
  build_test: ^0.10.1
  build_web_compilers: ^0.3.6
web:
  compiler:
    debug: dartdevc
```

The Error when running `pub get`

`Because angular_compiler >=0.2.1 <0.3.0+1 depends on build ^0.10.0 and no versions of angular_compiler match >0.3.0+1 <0.4.0, angular_compiler >=0.2.1 <0.3.0+1 or >0.3.0+1 <0.4.0  requires build ^0.10.0.
And because angular >=4.0.0-beta <5.0.0-alpha depends on angular_compiler ^0.3.0, angular >=4.0.0-beta <5.0.0-alpha requires build ^0.10.0 or angular_compiler 0.3.0+1. And because angular_compiler 0.3.0+1 depends on build >=0.10.0 <0.12.0 and build_web_compilers >=0.2.1 depends on build ^0.12.0, angular >=4.0.0-beta <5.0.0-alpha is incompatible with
  build_web_compilers >=0.2.1.
So, because JRapha depends on both angular ^4.0.0 and build_web_compilers ^0.3.6, version solving
  failed.`

Is there a solution to running AngularDart4 with Dart v2?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it is not compatible.

Only AngularDart v5 is compatible with Dart2 and `build_runner`.